# Dealing with extreme unbalanced multiclasses in logistic regression classifier in sklearn python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sampling, logistic-regression

I would like to classify some label (10 classes) using 100000. But the data has an extreme imbalance, for example, two classes each consists of 30% of the overall data, while some classes be ~0.01%. Thus I used lr = LogisticRegression(class_weight="auto") instead of lr = LogisticRegression(). I found that my precision and recall measures perform much worse (precision:78% recall:64% to precision:62% recall:57%), after adding class_weight="auto", is it common or am I doing something wrong?

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import nltk
import re
import random
from random import randint
import csv
import dask.dataframe as dd
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

lr = LogisticRegression(class_weight="auto")
dv = DictVectorizer()
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8")
df = DataFrame(data)

# Random sampling a smaller dataframe for debugging
rows = random.sample(df.index, 100000)
df = df.ix[rows] # Warning!!!! overwriting original df

# Assign X and y variables
X = df.raw_name.values
y = df.ethnicity2.values

# Feature extraction functions
def feature_full_last_name(nameString):
    try:
        last_name = nameString.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
        if len(last_name) > 1: # not accept name with only 1 character
            return last_name
        else: return '?'
    except: return '?'

# Transform format of X variables, and spit out a numpy array for all features
my_dict = [{'last-name': feature_full_last_name(i)} for i in X]

all_dict = my_dict

newX = dv.fit_transform(all_dict).toarray()

# Separate the training and testing data sets
half_cut = int(len(df)/2.0)*-1
X_train = newX[:half_cut]
X_test = newX[half_cut:]
y_train = y[:half_cut]
y_test = y[half_cut:]

# Fitting X and y into model, using training data
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Making predictions using trained data
y_train_predictions = lr.predict(X_train)
y_test_predictions = lr.predict(X_test)

print (y_train_predictions == y_train).sum().astype(float)/(y_train.shape[0])
print (y_test_predictions == y_test).sum().astype(float)/(y_test.shape[0])
```

Edited outputs:

```
Frequent label      
           w/auto   w/o auto
Error rate  0.22866 0.186724
Accuracy    0.77134 0.813276
Precision   0.921246774 0.854109238
Recall  0.511857815 0.636206455


Infrequent label    
           w/auto   w/o auto
Error rate  0.098096    0.007652
Accuracy    0.901904    0.992348
Precision   0.995609966 0.992641816
Recall  0.047821338 0.780346821
```

Answer (score 3):

With the multiclass classification problem like that you described, you're going to be giving a lot of weight to the very small minority classes - thus the model will favor getting those few observations right over getting the other, more populous, classes correct.

A side effect of this could be what you're seeing, with overall precision and recall decreasing. However, I suspect that you are doing a better job of predicting those low-observation classes.

Thus you'll only want to use the `class_weight` option if you really care about predicting those low-observation classes more than you do the other classes.

Comment: Hi, I have since run some test and added on the 'edited' section above. For both frequent and non-frequent label, the addition of 'auto' improves the precision a little bit. But their recall measures suffer especially for the non-frequent label. Is there a rule of thumb of using 'auto'? It looks like without 'auto' they do much better.

Answer (score 0):

@Tchotchke is right, but i'll try to explain this in other way:

You should think about general distribution of classes in your dataset. Is your dataset imbalanced because of bad sampling (Someone just deleted part of dataset with some classes), or because of real-world probability of class occurrence?

You can change class weights in both cases. In first case you may change weights to fix distribution, but in second case you should know that changing class and sample frequencies may affect decision boundary, because every estimator takes into consideration probability of occurrence for every class. 
And if you deviate from real-world probability distribution over classes you often achieve a bad classifier, because probability of some class occurrence is part of a dataset too, it's useful information. Thus in most cases you should change weights of classes/samples only if you have doubts about dataset fairness, and you want to correct it.

But in some cases you can change weights of some class even if your dataset captures real-world distribution between classes. For example if you want to classify if some person has a cancer. Turns out that if you sample dataset from some population, only very small amount of persons will have a cancer, but in this task it's better to label person as ill in cases when classifier is not certain about actual label, i.e. this person maybe healthy, but it's better to classify him as sick and make additional tests to make final decision , than to label him as healthy, if it has cancer, and now he will think that he is healthy. So by changing class weights you will change class distribution, sum of weights over cancerous samples would be same as for healthy samples. Classifier trained on such dataset would label healthy persons as ill in more cases (more false positives), but it would tag an ill person as healthy rarely, which is more important. Overall accuracy of classification decreases, but who cares? Our task is detecting all ill persons, instead of detecting whether some person ill or healthy.